# Using a WSDL File to Submit XML file through web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wsdl

I am using ASP.NET and C# to display a form for someone to complete and submit a request to an external company on a button click. The company provided a WSDL file which i was able to import into my Solution as a Web Reference. Once I added the reference it generated a bunch of classes which appears to create an XML file and from what I understand is what I need to do. I given an example of what an XML file submittion looks like but I am a little confused on how to the web reference and submit the request.

Here is the [WSDL](https://data-test.thermoking.com/ws/ThermoKingWebServices.SubmitClaim:getSubmitClaimWSD?WSDL)

I am trying call the complextype (method) ClaimSubmittalRequest
This is what I was able to do in my C# code (get and set the fields):

```
        var submitClaim = new ThermalKing.SubmitClaimRequest
        {
            claimLanguage = "ENG",
            serviceVersion = "1.0",
            claimType = "PARTS",
            failureDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 26),
            faultFound = "PERFORM A FREE INSPECTION"
        };

        var submitParts = new ThermalKing.eachPart
        {
            partNumber = "1234",
            partPrice = 100.78,
            partQuantity = 17
        };
```

Here is what the example XML File looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:get="http://data-test.thermoking.com/ThermoKingWebServices/SubmitClaim/getSubmitClaimWSD">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <get:getSubmitClaim>
         <SubmitClaimRequest>

            <buName>Thermo King TSA</buName>
            <dealerNumber>P5358</dealerNumber>
            <userName></userName>
            <password></password>

            <transactionType>WARRANTY</transactionType>
            <claimType>Machine</claimType>

            <inventorySerialNumber>6001061225</inventorySerialNumber>

            <repairDate>2011-09-05T00:00:00.000-05:00</repairDate>
            <failureDate>2011-09-05T00:00:00.000-05:00</failureDate>

            <workOrderNumber>testProcede1</workOrderNumber>
            <conditionsFound>test</conditionsFound>
            <workPerformed>test</workPerformed>
            <claimNotes>test claim notes</claimNotes>

            <!-- will be optional fields in the future -->
              <faultLocation>FF</faultLocation>
              <faultFound>BLOWN/BURST</faultFound>
              <failureDetail xsi:nil="true"/>

            <smrClaim>N</smrClaim>
            <forceToDraft>Y</forceToDraft>
            <validateOnly>N</validateOnly>
            <commercialPolicy>N</commercialPolicy>

            <!-- will be optional fields in the future -->
              <fuelSurcharge>0</fuelSurcharge>
              <shopSupplies>0</shopSupplies>

            <claimCurrency>USD</claimCurrency>
            <workOrderSegment>1</workOrderSegment>
            <claimLanguage>ENG</claimLanguage>
            <serviceVersion>1.0</serviceVersion>

            <partsType>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <eachPart>
                  <partType>IRREMOVED</partType>
                  <partNumber>416780</partNumber>
                  <partQuantity>1.0</partQuantity>
                  <partPrice>1.23</partPrice>
                  <partDescription>test part desc</partDescription>
               </eachPart>
               <eachPart>
                  <partType>NONIR</partType>
                  <partNumber>1</partNumber>
                  <partQuantity>1.0</partQuantity>
                  <partPrice>1</partPrice>
                  <partDescription>test non IR</partDescription>
               </eachPart>
               <eachPart>
                  <partType>IRINSTALLED</partType>
                  <partNumber>416780</partNumber>
                  <partQuantity>1.0</partQuantity>
                  <partPrice>1</partPrice>
                  <partDescription>test ir installed</partDescription>
               </eachPart>
            </partsType>

            <jobCodesType>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <eachJobCode>
                  <jobCode>05051</jobCode>
                  <standardLaborHours>1</standardLaborHours>
                  <additionalLaborHours>.5</additionalLaborHours>
                  <laborRate>92.22</laborRate>
                  <ReasonForAdditionalLaborHours>test</ReasonForAdditionalLaborHours>
               </eachJobCode>
            </jobCodesType>

            <usageMetersType>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <eachUsageMeter>
                  <usageAmount>1661</usageAmount>
                  <usageType>HoursInService</usageType>
                  <usageUOM>HOURS</usageUOM>
               </eachUsageMeter>
            </usageMetersType>


         </SubmitClaimRequest>
      </get:getSubmitClaim>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I call the Complex Type Method in my C# code to send the request to the external company? Or is it easier just to create an XML file manually using C#?

UPDATED CODE:

```
    using (var client = new getSubmitClaimWSD_PortTypeClient())
    {
        SubmitClaimRequest request = new SubmitClaimRequest()
        {
            buName = "Thermo King TSA",
            dealerNumber = "PHSDF",
            userName = "Roger",
            password = "1234",
            transactionType = "WARRANTY",
            claimLanguage = "ENG",
            serviceVersion = "1.0",
            claimType = "PARTS",
            failureDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 26),
            faultFound = "PERFORM A FREE INSPECTION",
            inventorySerialNumber = "12352341",
            repairDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 26),
            workOrderNumber = "testProcede1",
            conditionsFound = "test",
            workPerformed = "test",
            claimNotes = "test claim notes",
            faultLocation = "FF",
            failureDetail = "test",
            smrClaim = "N",
            forceToDraft = "Y",
            validateOnly = "N",
            commercialPolicy = "N",
            fuelSurcharge = 0,
            shopSupplies = 0,
            claimCurrency = "USD",
            workOrderSegment = "1",
            partsType = new[]
            {
                new eachPart() {partNumber = "1234", partPrice = 100.78, partQuantity = 17, partType = "NONIR", partDescription = "test part desc"},
                new eachPart() {partNumber = "5678", partPrice = 200.90, partQuantity = 1, partType = "IRREMOVED", partDescription = "test part desc 2"}
            }
        };
        var response = client.getSubmitClaim(null, request);
        var rsp = response.response;
        Console.WriteLine("Status {0}, claim {1}; {2} {3}, {4} errors", rsp.status, rsp.claimNumber,
            rsp.workOrderNumber, rsp.workOrderSegment, rsp.errorsType.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Please see [How to consume a web service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/). You don't ever send "XML files".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I read that article. So basically I do not need to create my own web service that is why i have the wsdl. I just have to add the wsdl as the web reference that then apply my updated code?

Comment: No, don't create your own service. The article creates a service just as a demonstration. Just do the part that _uses_ the service. Your're already mostly there.

Comment: Neither of the things you have in the `using` blocks is the service. One is the request, and the other is part of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
using (var client = new SubmitClaimService.getSubmitClaimWSD_PortTypeClient())
{
    SubmitClaimRequest request = new SubmitClaimRequest()
    {
        claimLanguage = "ENG",
        serviceVersion = "1.0",
        claimType = "PARTS",
        failureDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 26),
        faultFound = "PERFORM A FREE INSPECTION",
        partsType =
            new[]
            {
                new eachPart() {partNumber = "1234", partPrice = 100.78, partQuantity = 17},
                new eachPart() {partNumber = "5678", partPrice = 200.90, partQuantity = 1}
            }
    };
    submitClaimResponse response = client.getSubmitClaim(request);
    var rsp = response.response;
    Console.WriteLine("Status {0}, claim {1}; {2} {3}, {4} errors", rsp.status, rsp.claimNumber,
        rsp.workOrderNumber, rsp.workOrderSegment, rsp.errorsType.Length);
}
```

I figured this out by right-clicking the service reference and choosing "View in object browser". Alternatively, you could bring up the Object Browser by using View->Object Browser, then navigate to the service reference.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. What did you do to add the service? When I add a service refference do I add the wsdl url in the url box?

Comment: Yes. Just paste in the URL: https://data-test.thermoking.com/ws/ThermoKingWebServices.SubmitClaim:getSubmitClaimWSD?WSDL

Comment: Okay, that's what I did too and there are no compiler errors or anything but I get an exception that states: There was no endpoint listening at http://data.thermoking.com:10141/ws/ThermoKingWebServices.SubmitClaim:getSubmitClaimWSD that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details

Comment: So the port got changed somehow. I fixed the port number and that got rid the above error but now on the line: var response = client.getSubmitClaim("true",request) I am getting an exception : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Mine doesn't have a "true", just `request`.

Comment: I am using 2013 Professional. When I have just request I am getting a compiler error saying that I need 2 parameters. Its a (string) testflag. I have tried having it null,true, y, and test and they are all the same error.